# display:block kills my style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table that has an inputbox in one of the  elements wich i use to filter the table with.

When i wright something in the box the table gets filtered.

The wierd thing is that if i use display:block to show the rows that I want to see it totally destroys the look of the row. But if I use jquery .toggle(); it works fine.

Why is that?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Users<input type="text" id="filter"/></th></tr>
        <tr class="user" data="patrick"><td>Patrick</td></tr>
        <tr class="user" data="john"><td>John</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Filter SCRIPT that works

```
$('#filter').keyup(function(){
    $(".user").css("display", "none");
    if($("#filter").val()!=''){             
        var filterstr = $("#filter").val().toLowerCase();
        $("[data*="+filterstr+"].user").toggle();
    }else{
        $(".user").toggle();
    }
});
```

If I use display:block

[image: With display:block]

CSS:

```
table
{
   width: 200px;
}
td
{
   border: 1px solid #000;
   font: bold 10px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   padding: 5px;
}
th
{
   background: #f3f3f3;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   font: bold 10px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: add your css....

Comment: and a jsfiddle please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:table-row` instead, because table rows are not `display:block` by default!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default display type of a table is not `display: block`, but is `display: table`. Each table body, row, cell, etc has their own display type also. I think JQuery's `toggle()` method sets the right display type depending on the element you are toggling.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the CSS, but it could be because "display:block;" adds a border to the input and toggle doesn't. Removing the border or widening the cell could work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display:block` on an element sets its display type to `block`.

However you're trying to do this on table elements, which have a different default display type and do not work well with `block`.

If you need to set the display type of these elements, you need to set them to `display:table`, `display:table-row` or `display:table-cell` depending on which elements you're setting.

Alternatively, you can just set it back to its default value, as follows:

```
$('myTableCell').css('display':'');
```

Setting the `display` property to an empty string in your jQuery code removes the inline style, and thus your normal CSS takes over, or the browser default if you haven't specified any CSS for the element.